# decreasing the height of the text box

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to decrease the height of the text box .style sheet does not seem to decrease the height of the text box. below is my code and style sheet.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<style>
.textmargin{
    margin-left: 50px;
}

.new5 {
    border: 5px solid green;
    border-radius: 2px;
}

.textBoxwidthlarge{

    width:40%
}

.textBoxwidthMedium {
    width: 20%
}
.textBoxwidthSmall {
    width: 40%
}

input[type="text"] {
    padding: 12px 10px;
    line-height: 2px;
    border: 2px solid black;
}
</style>
    <div class="col-md-12"><label for="fname" class="textmargin">First Name</label><br />
        <input type="text" runat="server"  class="input-field textmargin textBoxwidthlarge" id="name1" name="t1" /> </div>
```

I want the height like so:

[image]

any help will be appreciated. I have three text boxes inside a . I am only showing one above.

Comment: you're snippet isn't working properly how about a jsfiddle? i can edit there and help you out.

Comment: I just put the working code. Please try again. I cannot reduce the height of this text box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove all the unnecessary styles from your code and just keep one class to set its width.

```css
.textBoxwidthlarge {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="col-md-12"><label for="fname" class="textmargin">First Name</label><br />
  <input type="text" runat="server" class="input-field textmargin textBoxwidthlarge" id="name1" name="t1" /> </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

this way you can customize as you wish

```html
  <div class="col-md-4"><label for="fname" class="textmargin">First Name</label><br />
            <input type="text" runat="server"  class="textmargin textBoxwidthlarge txtboxhg" id="name1" name="t1" /> </div>
            
 <style>
input[type="text"]{ padding: 12px 10px; line-height: 12px; width:100%}
</style>
```

Comment: for some reason, height i not working on my code. I put the working code above

Answer (score 1):

To reduce the height of the text box and add a border, add

```
height: 1px;
border: 2px solid red;
```

to the **.txtboxhg** class

You can decide on your own color and border size.